# d garbage collector and realtime applications

Tags: garbage-collection, real-time, d

I'm thinking about learning D (basically "C++ done right and with garbage collection and message passing between threads") and talked to a colleague who's been long-time C++ programmer and basically he complained that the garbage collector as such has severe timing issues even in soft realtime type applications.

It's not that I need to write realtime app - far from it - but I'm curious how problematic GC would be in developing, say, database? (abstracting from additional memory usage overhead that GC seems to impose, statistically)

(now I know that GC can be turned off in D but that's like saying you can get rid of problems related to a car by getting rid of a car - true but that's not the solution I'd like to choose)

Is this true? How severe are such issues in practice? Is developing, say, a device driver in D and with use of GC is practical/sensible/good practice?

Comment: Millions of Java, C#, and JVM-based languages (Clojure, Scala, JRubi, Jython...) developers do not complain about GC. Furthermore, people from LMAX have proven that if developer understands the hardware, and tje JVM, they can write darn fast java apps... People who do not want to write GC-friendly code will always have to say something against GC...

Comment: @DejanLekic - that's true but not quite relevant to the context: I meant specifically low-level, high-performance, time-critical code. In all the thousands of lines of Python code I've written not once I had to pay any attention to GC-related issues. Those applications were not time-critical so this simply didn't matter. Device driver, however, and probably not even database, is not app of this type, hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While D has a GC, it does not force you to use it for *everything*. D also has structs, which act like C++ classes&structs(minus the polymorphism).

In modern managed languages, the GC is not a problem as long as you have enough memory. This is also true for unmanaged languages like C++ - but in C++, running out of memory means you can't allocate any more memory, while in Java running out of memory means a delay while the GC kicks in.

So, if you are planning to allocate tons of objects then yes - the GC can be a problem. But you probably don't really need to allocate so many objects. In Java, you have to use objects to store things like strings and dates and coordinates - and that can really fill up your heap and invoke the GC(luckily, modern JVM use generational GC to optimize those types of objects). In D, you'll just use structs for these things, and only use classes for cases that actually require GC.

As a rule of thumb, you'll usually want to use structs wherever you can, but if you find yourself doing something special to take care of deallocating or to prevent copying&destructing(though it's really fast in D) - make that type a class without a second thought.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't really approve of the statement "as long as you have enough memory a GC is not a problem". I mean, that basically means, you goahead and waste your memory instead of properly taking care of it and when it's out you suddenly have to wait 1> second for the GC to collect everything.

For one thing, that only happens if it's a really bad GC. The GC in c# for example collects objects extremly fast and often. You won't get a problem, even if you allocate in an often used function and it won't wait till you run out of memory to do a collection.

I am not fully up to date on the current features of the D2 GC (we use D1) but the behavior at the time was that it would allocate a pool of memory and for each of your allocations it would give you some of it. When it has given out 90% and you need more it would start a collection and/or allocate more from the system. (or something like that). There is (for D1) also the concurrent GC which would start collections earlier, but having them run in the background, but it is linux-only as it uses the fork syscall.

So, I think the current D GC can cause small but noticable freezes if not used with care. But you can disable/enable it, e.g. when you do something real-time critical, disable it, when that critical part of the code is over, enable it again.

For a database, I don't think the D GC is ready yet. I would heavily re-use memory and not rely on the GC at all for that kind of application.